# Grease pencil object is refusing visual effects

Tags: modeling, grease-pencil, workbench-render-engine

I'm new to blender 2.92 and I've a book with cool tutorial series with quick-start guides for blender 2.80, and I've learned many things so far! But a problem arises when I try to apply an effect to suzanne object:
[image]

The glow effect is ignored.

As shown above, nothing happens and I did everything I could for hours... I applied all properties in sidebar, but they are being ignored...

I know that the lessons are meant for 2.80, I keep up updated with latest online manual docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be in Rendered view to see Grease Pencil effects.

[image]

Comment: It looks like I had to disable scene world too... It's making things kinda awkward. I can't see the effects without disabling it.

Comment: Yes it's not really user-friendly... Did you add actual lights to your scene ?

Comment: I don't know... I think it was added by default? BTW, what happened to radius? I can't increase it's intensity...